# Format Select2 dropdown results having json

Tags: jquery, json, select, jquery-select2, ui-select2

I am using select2 dropdown control to display list of facilities e.g facility A,B,C...etc. along with its location details. I am looking for following output,

[image]

Currently I can display "facility name", but would like to display City and State from my json objects.
**How can I format my results to display them as above html format?**
Here's my code so far.

```
<input type="hidden" id="ddlFacility" style="width:100%" />

$("#ddlFacility").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a Facility",
        ajax: {
            url: "my url",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "GET",
            quietMillis: 50,
            data: function ( term ) { return { term: term }; },
            results: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { text: item.FacilityName, id: item.FacilityId }
                    })
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your select2 options pass a function something like this and style the classes however you need

```
...
placeholder: "Select a Facility",
    formatResult: function(item)
    { 
         return '<div class="facility">' + item.text + '</div><span class="city">' + item.city + '</span></div>';
    },
 ...
```

you may need your .map function to include Facilityname and City values in addition to id and text.

If you want the selected value to look the same, use the same function for the formatSelection option

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful. Just a small correction, in format result i have to make "item.text" instead of "item.FacilityName" otherwise it returns 'undefined.

Comment: Yup! I forgot it would already be mapped to id and text.  I've fixed it up for anyone else finding this.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that nowadays if using select2 version 4 or above the `formatSelection` and `formatResult` were replaced by `templateSelection` and `templateResult`
More details on the official documentation:
https://select2.org/upgrading/migrating-from-35